# AppScript issues with Cocoa NSString and AppleScript text types?

Tags: cocoa, text, nsstring, applescript, sdef

In one of my Applications I've added a few new properties to the `document` class of the Standard AppleScript suite. Some of these properties have the type `text`, others have the type `boolean`. I've written a "sdef" file and added if to the resources of my App.

But when I launch the App, there are messages in the Console like this:

> .sdef warning for type 'text' attribute 'title' of class 'window' in
>   suite 'Standard Suite': AppleScript name references may not work for
>   this property because its type is not NSString-derived.

And when I actually try to get the value from such a new property with type `text` from within an AppleScript, it will fail. The correct method within my App is called, and it returns the correct value as `NSString`, but the AppleScript returns with an error. There's a message in the Console again:

> Error while returning the result of a script command: the result
>   object... "the requested NSString value"  ...could not be converted to
>   an Apple event descriptor of type 'text'. This instance of the class
>   '__NSCFString' returned nil when sent -objectSpecifier (is it not
>   overridden?) and there is no coercible type declared for the scripting
>   class 'text'.

Which probably means that it was not possible to convert the Cocoa `NSString` object into an AppleScript `text` object.

When I try to get the value from one of the new boolean properties, it works just fine.

What exactly do I need to do to convert a `NSString` object into an AppleScript `text` object?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's difficult to diagnose. My initial questions would be 1) is the memory being released properly and 2) are you creating the NSString properly?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to coerce the text parameter into a NSString.

I.e

```
Set sometextString to current application's NSString's stringwithTring:atext
```

Use it in your method

And to return it you do.

```
Return sometextString as text
```